# O365 - Limit user consent for external apps

Tags: permissions, office365, azure-activedirectory

O365 and OAuth2 allows users to give 3rd party apps consent to access data on behalf of the user.
Is there any way we can limit the "scope" of consent the user allow ?

Since we are in the EU, and thus hit by GDPR, and we consider e-mails as containing personal data, then we can not legally allow 3rd parties access to users e-mail without a data processor agreement, risk assessment etc in place. The 3rd party would process data.

We can get the granted permissions on a per user basis, and do our own reporting and followup. But it would be better to say users can NOT give 3rd party apps any sort of e-mail, calendar and Contacts (that is by definition personal data) permission.

We can disallow all 3rd party apps, by tuning integrated Apps off. But we still would allow the user to grant simple consent like: "openid profile email", "User.Read openid email profile offline_access"  or "User.Read"

Answer (score 0):

I think your specific requirement is not possible. The closest you can get is with Cloud App Security (still allowing end user flexibility): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/manage-app-permissions.
You can ban or allow apps and notify users automatically, but you need to review the new apps from time to time.

If you don't have the correct licenses yet, you can buy separate Cloud App Security licenses, it's also embedded in EM+S E5 or Microsoft 365 E5 (or even Microsoft 365 E3 + E5 Secure).

Answer (score 0):

I know that we tend to have wishes way forward of the leading edge, or vendors just being incredible slow to implement sensible features.

I am currently running a report, extracting info on what people has already granted consent to, so I have some data to justify the disabling user content completely (if that is possible). But for my 75k identities in AAD (not all with a license) it takes some time.

My script has not found any 3rd party access by now, but we had a user last week asking if he could use a smart inbox and GTD tool. So at least we have some awareness, and well behaved users. But I am afraid that at some point people will start using suspicious stuff.